# Any interesting properties of the matrix $M:=(m_{ij})$ with $m_{ij}=\min(i,j)$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis

Let $n \times n$ matrix $M(n):=(m_{ij})$ be defined by $$m_{ij} = \min(i,j)$$

This matrix enumerates certain combinatorial objects. Do you know any interesting properties of matrix $M$?

Comment: Could you make precise the motivation ? which sort of combinatorial objects are enumerated ?

Comment: This is a very interesting matrix (Brownian bridge kernel); for instance, see section 3 of my notes: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4107v2.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the information. The enumeration is related with the counting of certain vertex-weighted graph.

Comment: See arxiv:math/0606163 by Bona, Ju and Yoshida.

Answer (score 6):

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be the upper triangular matrix such that
$a_{ij}=
\begin{cases}
1, \textrm{if $i \leq j$}\\
0, \textrm{else}
\end{cases}$, then the matrix $M$ is equal to the product $A^{T}A$. Many interesting properties of $M$ follow from this.

For example, one concludes that $M$ has determinant $1$, and is positive definite. What else do you want to know?